# Serialization error: Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an object with nested serialization so other objects that relate to it are also created. I've overridden the **create()** method for ModelSerializer and the main object is created successfully.

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        post_data = validated_data.pop('post_set')
        big_post = BigPost.objects.create(**validated_data) // This works
        for post in post_data:
            e = PostSerializer(data=post)
            if e.is_valid():
                e.save()
            else:
                print(e.errors) // Prints 'Incorrect type' error
        return big_post
```

However, when trying to create the nested object (Post), I get this error:

> {'note': ['Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Note.']}

'note' is a field of the PostSerializer as shown below:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'note', 'title', 'description')
```

I am aware that default behaviour of ModelSerializer is to create PrimaryKeyRelatedField for any related fields of the model. But, I don't know why an instance is being created when the data submitted is just a PK like so: {"note":3, ....}

Comment: Have you tried solution below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your serializers defined properly, you don't need to deserialize validated_data for the second time.

Docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Try this code:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

class BigPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = PostSerializer(source='post_set', many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post_data = validated_data.pop('post_set')
        big_post = BigPost.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for post in post_data:
            e = Post.objects.create(bigpost=big_post, **post)

        return big_post
```

bigpost - is the name of foreign key to BigPost.

Comment: Hi, I am aware that this can be done and have seen the docs example that implements it. However, I was hoping that there was a way to do this by calling the nested serializer. This is because I have another nested object that needs to be created inside 'post_data'. Also, I would like the serializer to enforce validation of the nested objects.

Comment: Just nest serializers like in the example.

Comment: I currently have code that is similar to yours but, in the create method, you have used Post.object.create(). Whereas, I would like to use the PostSerializer(data) with .save(). This will then call create() of the PostSerializer and will call another one. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Then you need to pass nested data as text field and deserialize it from field. In validated_data you have deserialized data with handled nesting as defined by serializers relations.

Comment: Ah I think I misunderstood how the serialization works. I have used the original solution. Thanks.

Comment: @DmitryShilyaev I  am doing exactly as you suggested, though getting error - bigpost : [ "This field is required."]. Also it seems like in my case its not even hitting create override. (p.s. I am using generics.ListCreateAPIView which is then have serializer with parent model.

Comment: "This field is required." means that you miss bigpost field.

Comment: @DmitryShilyaev Since the `post` object is created without calling its serializer (`PostSerializer`), this doesn't hit the `validate` method nor the `validate_<field>` methods of the `PostSerializer`, thus allowing invalid data to be populated.